# Can std::memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release be used separately?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) says that `std::memory_order_acquire` will prevent read and write from reordering before it. So I can use `std::memory_order_acquire` just for preventing from reorder at run-time without corresponding `std::memory_order_release`. For example

```
#include <atomic>
#include <stdint.h>

std::atomic<uint32_t> g_counter{};//Counter for thread in Fun
std::atomic<void*> g_data{};
void Fun()
{
    g_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);//Warning:`fetch_add` maybe reorder after next 'load'
    void *data = g_data.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    g_counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);//just memory_order_relaxed will be ok
}
```

Is that true?

Comment: The [Release-Acquire_ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering) is usually specified w.r.t to two or more threads. There need not be an acquire and release in the same thread.

Comment: @P.W: But as what i known, even in the same thread, the reorder is possible without any memory barrier at runtime.

Comment: Why do you care about reordering within a single thread? Your program doesn't have any way to observe it, even if it did occur; it would work exactly the same either way.

Comment: I want to know how many threads exactly it is running in the Fun. Something like resource reclaim can be done if no thread is in the Fun. e.g:
if(g_counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0)
{
    //reclaim data buffers
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days learning. I think 'release' and 'acuire' can be used separately to prevent corresponding reordering . But there is something wrong with the example. That is a store operation about 'fetch_add' , and the store maybe reorder after the next load. The right way is change both of the fetch_add and next load to be memory_order_seq_cst operation.